# Determine the quadratic character of the given numbers modulo the prime 379.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

a.) -1

b.) 307

I solved the same problem for 3, 5 and 60 but am having a tough time with these remaining two. Help with either one is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

a) For the odd prime $p$, $-1$ is a QR of $p$ if $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, and a NR of $p$ if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.

b) As for $307$, there are many ways. For example by Reciprocity we have $(307/379)=-(379/307)=-(72/307)=-(2/307)$. But $2$ is a QR of the odd prime $p$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm -1\pmod{8}$. Since $307$ is not of that form, we have $(2/307)=-1$, and therefore $(307/379)=1$.

Or else note that $307\equiv -72\pmod{379}$, and therefore $(307/379)=(-1/379)(72/379)=(-1/379)(2/379)$. Each of these Legendre symbols is equal to $-1$.